# When saving a file to RackSpace CloudFiles using Paperclip/Fog, a timeout occurs, when connecting to odd IP address

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip, rackspace-cloud, fog, excon

I have an app that stores images on RackSpace CloudFiles using Paperclip. It's been working fine, but recently it won't save files. The error that occurs is:

```
Excon::Errors::SocketError (Connection timed out - connect(2) for 94.236.107.224:443 (Errno::ETIMEDOUT)):
```

In `excon/socket.rb` I have added some debugging to see the content of `@data` at the point the request is made. This is:

```
{
  :chunk_size        => 1048576, 
  :ciphers           => "HIGH:!SSLv2:!aNULL:!eNULL:!3DES", 
  :connect_timeout   => 60, 
  :debug_request     => false, 
  :debug_response    => true, 
  :headers           => {"User-Agent" => "fog/1.22.0"}, 
  :idempotent        => false, 
  :instrumentor_name => "excon", 
  :middlewares       => [Excon::Middleware::ResponseParser, Excon::Middleware::Expects, Excon::Middleware::Idempotent, Excon::Middleware::Instrumentor, Excon::Middleware::Mock],
  :mock              => false,
  :nonblock          => true,
  :omit_default_port => false,
  :persistent        => false,
  :read_timeout      => 60,
  :retry_limit       => 4,
  :ssl_verify_peer   => true,
  :tcp_nodelay       => false,
  :uri_parser        => URI,
  :write_timeout     => 60,
  :host              => "lon.auth.api.rackspacecloud.com",
  :path              => "/v2.0",
  :port              => 443,
  :query             => nil,
  :scheme            => "https",
  :user              => nil,
  :password          => nil
}
```

The host is `lon.auth.api.rackspacecloud.com`, which resolves to `92.52.64.197` (on the server, as well as locally).

However the error is because the connection to `94.236.107.224` times out. A reverse lookup on that IP shows it is also associated with the auth hostname:

```
$ host 94.236.107.224
224.107.236.94.in-addr.arpa domain name pointer lon.auth.api.rackspacecloud.com.
```

I presume this IP is no longer in use for the auth service, but I can't see why it's being connected to at all.

So I need to know:

1. Why is the bad IP being connected to, when it doesn't show up in the log?
2. How do I fix this so that the correct server is used?

Here is the full error that occurs:

```
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 15437.6ms

Excon::Errors::SocketError (Connection timed out - connect(2) for 94.236.107.224:443 (Errno::ETIMEDOUT)):
  excon (0.33.0) lib/excon/socket.rb:220:in `connect_nonblock'
  excon (0.33.0) lib/excon/socket.rb:220:in `rescue in block in connect'
  excon (0.33.0) lib/excon/socket.rb:189:in `block in connect'
  excon (0.33.0) lib/excon/socket.rb:185:in `each'
  excon (0.33.0) lib/excon/socket.rb:185:in `connect'
  excon (0.33.0) lib/excon/ssl_socket.rb:131:in `connect'
  excon (0.33.0) lib/excon/socket.rb:28:in `initialize'
  excon (0.33.0) lib/excon/ssl_socket.rb:9:in `initialize'
  excon (0.33.0) lib/excon/connection.rb:414:in `new'
  excon (0.33.0) lib/excon/connection.rb:414:in `socket'
  excon (0.33.0) lib/excon/connection.rb:126:in `request_call'
  excon (0.33.0) lib/excon/middlewares/mock.rb:42:in `request_call'
  excon (0.33.0) lib/excon/middlewares/instrumentor.rb:22:in `request_call'
  excon (0.33.0) lib/excon/middlewares/base.rb:15:in `request_call'
  excon (0.33.0) lib/excon/middlewares/base.rb:15:in `request_call'
  excon (0.33.0) lib/excon/middlewares/base.rb:15:in `request_call'
  excon (0.33.0) lib/excon/connection.rb:269:in `request'
  fog-core (1.22.0) lib/fog/core/connection.rb:56:in `request'
  fog (1.22.0) lib/fog/rackspace/service.rb:34:in `request_without_retry'
  fog (1.22.0) lib/fog/rackspace/requests/identity/create_token.rb:15:in `create_token'
  fog (1.22.0) lib/fog/rackspace/identity.rb:41:in `authenticate'
  fog (1.22.0) lib/fog/rackspace/identity.rb:79:in `initialize'
  fog-core (1.22.0) lib/fog/core/service.rb:115:in `new'
  fog-core (1.22.0) lib/fog/core/service.rb:115:in `new'
  fog (1.22.0) lib/fog/rackspace/service.rb:116:in `authenticate_v2'
  fog (1.22.0) lib/fog/rackspace/service.rb:30:in `authenticate'
  fog (1.22.0) lib/fog/rackspace/storage.rb:88:in `authenticate'
  fog (1.22.0) lib/fog/rackspace/storage.rb:419:in `initialize'
  fog-core (1.22.0) lib/fog/core/service.rb:115:in `new'
  fog-core (1.22.0) lib/fog/core/service.rb:115:in `new'
  fog-core (1.22.0) lib/fog/storage.rb:26:in `new'
  paperclip (3.4.2) lib/paperclip/storage/fog.rb:208:in `connection'
  paperclip (3.4.2) lib/paperclip/storage/fog.rb:218:in `directory'
  paperclip (3.4.2) lib/paperclip/storage/fog.rb:100:in `block in flush_writes'
  paperclip (3.4.2) lib/paperclip/storage/fog.rb:96:in `each'
  paperclip (3.4.2) lib/paperclip/storage/fog.rb:96:in `flush_writes'
  paperclip (3.4.2) lib/paperclip/attachment.rb:221:in `save'
  paperclip (3.4.2) lib/paperclip/instance_methods.rb:17:in `block in save_attached_files'
  paperclip (3.4.2) lib/paperclip/instance_methods.rb:10:in `block in each_attachment'
  paperclip (3.4.2) lib/paperclip/instance_methods.rb:9:in `each'
  paperclip (3.4.2) lib/paperclip/instance_methods.rb:9:in `each_attachment'
  paperclip (3.4.2) lib/paperclip/instance_methods.rb:16:in `save_attached_files'
  activesupport (3.2.17) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:449:in `_run__806665839013247154__save__3701132647492051879__callbacks'
  activesupport (3.2.17) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `__run_callback'
  activesupport (3.2.17) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:385:in `_run_save_callbacks'
  activesupport (3.2.17) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
  activerecord (3.2.17) lib/active_record/callbacks.rb:264:in `create_or_update'
  activerecord (3.2.17) lib/active_record/persistence.rb:84:in `save'
  activerecord (3.2.17) lib/active_record/validations.rb:50:in `save'
  activerecord (3.2.17) lib/active_record/attribute_methods/dirty.rb:22:in `save'
  activerecord (3.2.17) lib/active_record/transactions.rb:259:in `block (2 levels) in save'
  activerecord (3.2.17) lib/active_record/transactions.rb:313:in `block in with_transaction_returning_status'
  activerecord (3.2.17) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:192:in `transaction'
  activerecord (3.2.17) lib/active_record/transactions.rb:208:in `transaction'
  activerecord (3.2.17) lib/active_record/transactions.rb:311:in `with_transaction_returning_status'
  activerecord (3.2.17) lib/active_record/transactions.rb:259:in `block in save'
  activerecord (3.2.17) lib/active_record/transactions.rb:270:in `rollback_active_record_state!'
  activerecord (3.2.17) lib/active_record/transactions.rb:258:in `save'
  activeadmin (0.5.1) lib/active_admin/resource_controller/callbacks.rb:28:in `block in save_resource'
  activeadmin (0.5.1) lib/active_admin/callbacks.rb:78:in `run_save_callbacks'
  activeadmin (0.5.1) lib/active_admin/resource_controller/callbacks.rb:27:in `save_resource'
  activeadmin (0.5.1) lib/active_admin/resource_controller/callbacks.rb:22:in `block in create_resource'
  activeadmin (0.5.1) lib/active_admin/callbacks.rb:78:in `run_create_callbacks'
  activeadmin (0.5.1) lib/active_admin/resource_controller/callbacks.rb:21:in `create_resource'
  inherited_resources (1.4.1) lib/inherited_resources/actions.rb:33:in `create'
  activeadmin (0.5.1) lib/active_admin/resource_controller/actions.rb:48:in `create'
  actionpack (3.2.17) lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:4:in `send_action'
  actionpack (3.2.17) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:167:in `process_action'
  actionpack (3.2.17) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:10:in `process_action'
  actionpack (3.2.17) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:18:in `block in process_action'
  activesupport (3.2.17) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:458:in `_run__2901337515923689909__process_action__4396305873998292606__callbacks'
  activesupport (3.2.17) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `__run_callback'
  activesupport (3.2.17) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:385:in `_run_process_action_callbacks'
  activesupport (3.2.17) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
  actionpack (3.2.17) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:17:in `process_action'
  actionpack (3.2.17) lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:29:in `process_action'
  actionpack (3.2.17) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:30:in `block in process_action'
  activesupport (3.2.17) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:123:in `block in instrument'
  activesupport (3.2.17) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
  activesupport (3.2.17) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:123:in `instrument'
  actionpack (3.2.17) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:29:in `process_action'
  actionpack (3.2.17) lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:207:in `process_action'
  activerecord (3.2.17) lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:18:in `process_action'
  actionpack (3.2.17) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:121:in `process'
  actionpack (3.2.17) lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:45:in `process'
  actionpack (3.2.17) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:203:in `dispatch'
  actionpack (3.2.17) lib/action_controller/metal/rack_delegation.rb:14:in `dispatch'
  actionpack (3.2.17) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:246:in `block in action'
  actionpack (3.2.17) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:73:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.17) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:73:in `dispatch'
  actionpack (3.2.17) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:36:in `call'
  journey (1.0.4) lib/journey/router.rb:68:in `block in call'
  journey (1.0.4) lib/journey/router.rb:56:in `each'
  journey (1.0.4) lib/journey/router.rb:56:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.17) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:608:in `call'
  rack-google_analytics (1.0.2) lib/rack/google_analytics.rb:5:in `call'
  warden (1.2.3) lib/warden/manager.rb:35:in `block in call'
  warden (1.2.3) lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `catch'
  warden (1.2.3) lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.17) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/best_standards_support.rb:17:in `call'
  rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/etag.rb:23:in `call'
  rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/conditionalget.rb:35:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.17) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/head.rb:14:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.17) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:21:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.17) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb:242:in `call'
  rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:210:in `context'
  rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:205:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.17) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:341:in `call'
  activerecord (3.2.17) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:64:in `call'
  activerecord (3.2.17) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:479:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.17) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:28:in `block in call'
  activesupport (3.2.17) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `_run__1208023080139519486__call__3701132647492051879__callbacks'
  activesupport (3.2.17) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `__run_callback'
  activesupport (3.2.17) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:385:in `_run_call_callbacks'
  activesupport (3.2.17) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
  actionpack (3.2.17) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.17) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:31:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.17) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:16:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.17) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:56:in `call'
  railties (3.2.17) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:32:in `call_app'
  railties (3.2.17) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:16:in `block in call'
  activesupport (3.2.17) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:22:in `tagged'
  railties (3.2.17) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:16:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.17) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:22:in `call'
  rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'
  rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
  activesupport (3.2.17) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:72:in `call'
  rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/lock.rb:15:in `call'
  rack-cache (1.2) lib/rack/cache/context.rb:136:in `forward'
  rack-cache (1.2) lib/rack/cache/context.rb:143:in `pass'
  rack-cache (1.2) lib/rack/cache/context.rb:155:in `invalidate'
  rack-cache (1.2) lib/rack/cache/context.rb:71:in `call!'
  rack-cache (1.2) lib/rack/cache/context.rb:51:in `call'
  railties (3.2.17) lib/rails/engine.rb:484:in `call'
  railties (3.2.17) lib/rails/application.rb:231:in `call'
  railties (3.2.17) lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `method_missing'
  /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/passenger-4.0.35/lib/phusion_passenger/rack/thread_handler_extension.rb:77:in `process_request'
  /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/passenger-4.0.35/lib/phusion_passenger/request_handler/thread_handler.rb:142:in `accept_and_process_next_request'
  /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/passenger-4.0.35/lib/phusion_passenger/request_handler/thread_handler.rb:110:in `main_loop'
  /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/passenger-4.0.35/lib/phusion_passenger/request_handler.rb:441:in `block (3 levels) in start_threads'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to @geemus, @Kyle-Rames, and @AshWilson for clues to the puzzle.

RS support told me to change the auth server to `lon.identity.api.rackspacecloud.com` which I did but then saw the error:

```
Unknown region :dfw for service cloudFiles. Please use one of the following regions: :lon
```

Setting the region with `rackspace_region: :lon` in `paperclip_defaults.rb` sorted that, and got things working again.

Answer (score 2):

I was able to successfully authenticate against `lon.auth.api.rackspacecloud.com`. My guess is that there might be something wrong with the DNS configuration. Let me track someone down to investigate this issue for you.

Kyle

Comment: Thanks Kyle. Someone at RS support suggested I switch to lon.identity.api.rackspacecloud.com which seems to help, but then I get the error: `Unknown region :dfw for service cloudFiles. Please use one of the following regions: :lon` - looks promising but not sure where to set that (or where :dfw comes from.

Comment: @Colin That's the "region" - you can set it by providing "`rackspace_region: :lon`" where you pass the rest of your credentials (username, API key) to Paperclip. :-)

Comment: I have created a pull request to address this in fog. https://github.com/fog/fog/pull/2916

Answer (score 1):

I'm not certain about the specifics on the Rackspace side of things that would result in this. Within excon the resolution to ip happens within `Excon::Socket#connect`. Not sure how much you know about the nitty-gritty of these things, but thought I would at least point you in that direction in case it might help: https://github.com/geemus/excon/blob/master/lib/excon/socket.rb#L167

That just stays at the socket level at least at presently (we just look this up once at socket connect, and don't propagate it to the data hash). You shouldn't need to override this though (at least in my experience the default behavior is the right one). I'd probably just recommend filing the issue on github against fog at this point (https://github.com/fog/fog/issues/new) so that I can point Rackspace folks at it.

Comment: Thanks. I'll do that if Kyle doesn't manage to sort something out.